# Is dBase extension available for PHP 7?

Tags: php, php-7, pecl, dbase

I did a lot of research to find the dbase DLL for PHP 7 and I did not find it. Does one actually exist?

Is a way to rebuild the dbase.dll from the old version to make a new one?

```
[15-Oct-2015 23:20:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: dbase: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20141001
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

In this error we can see that the module was compiled with the module 20131226, there is a way to take it and rebuild it with the new module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this on github. You can try it. When I try it there was no errors and file was created.

https://github.com/mote0230/dbase-pecl-php7

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, [dbase](https://pecl.php.net/package/dbase) has not been updated in more than three years.

It is not prepared for PHP7, doesn't seem to have an active maintainer, and likely won't be available.

You cannot rebuild a DLL.

Comment: Thank you, do you know any option that i can do to be able to  read my dbf? Can i make my own dll to read it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the format. In the general case, you sure can make an extension, but I can't say if that's a good idea here or not ...

Answer (score 1):

if there is no dbase extension on the server (perhaps due to php7 implementation delay), I found this pure PHP replacement:
https://github.com/donfbecker/php-dbase

Comment: This seems to me to be the most futureproof route.

Answer (score 0):

Version for PHP7 on Windows is available from https://pecl.php.net/package/dbase.

If you need `php_dbase.dll` for PHP 7.1 or PHP 7.2, you can go to https://github.com/nufue/pecl-dbase-windows.

Comment: For me that version caused segfault error (centos 6, php 7.1)